# Creating pages opens up modern view

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was trying to create a new page in sharepoint online. For some reason it is opening up in a different look and feel. please see below

[image]

how do i change back to the classic page creation ?

my page library looks like the below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Choose Admin centers and then SharePoint.
- Choose Settings.
- Next to SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience, select either Classic experience or New experience (auto-detect).

[image]

After that you will get your page in classic view.

Comment: i have done the above but its the same

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the pages library, you can select which content type you want on your new page. If you select Site Page you get the new Modern UI look, but if you select Wiki page, the old one will appear.

[image]

Comment: i couldn't find the above option. i have edited question